# Number theory on number of pairs on an interval

Tags: number-theory

How many pairs of integers $(m,n)$ are there such that $1<m<2012$ and

$5^n<2^m<2^{m+1} < 5^{n+1}$?

How could I start this question please?

Answer (score 1):

$$5^{866}<2^{2011}<2^{2012}<5^{867}$$

It is not hard to show there is at least one pair for each $n\geq 1$, for example

$5<8<16<25$

$25<32<64<125$ etc

So there are at least $866$ such pairs, but we need to count the triplets/ quadriplets (if exist in our range), for example,

$$125<128<256<512<625$$

Such cases would give us more than one pair for the specific $n$

Now observe that for each $2^m$ for some $m$ in the range, it must be between some consecutive power of $5$. For all $n\geq$, we can find $2^m$ such that both $2^m$ and $2^{m+1}$ are bounded by consecutive power of $5$. And so there is no power of 2 that is alone, by @sorbio35 .

Which means for each consecutive powers of $1\leq n\leq 866$, powers of two bounded in between must be duplets, triplets or (more 5-consecutives, etc). And since no $2^m$ can be counted twice, which means that all powers $1<m<2012$ should fall between some powers of $5$, but we only counted $866$ of $m$ (as duplets), so there are $2010-1-866*2=277$ ($-1$ is because $2^2$ is alone) powers of $2$ that are uncounted (and should be counted).

$277$ of them are the uncounted triplets, quadriplets, etc. So the total numbers of pairs should be $866+277=1143$

Comment: Sorry if the above answer sounds confusing. I am not a native English speaker. If anyone understand this, please help me edit it to make it fluent. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Set $\,m = \bigg\lceil{\dfrac{\ln5}{\ln2}}\bigg\rceil\left(n\right)\,$ and for any $n$ there is an $m$ to match it.

Comment: @Bubububu is correct in that I was seriously undercounting.  I'm not sure exactly why we subtract 866 exactly twice though.  Shouldn't there be a little more to the overcounting idea from Combinatorics?

Comment: because let's say $5^n<2^m<...<2^{m+k}<5^{n+1}$, there are $k+1$ powers of $2$ in between, which means we there are $k$ pairs of $m,n$. But we only count once if we count the number of $n$. Since for each duplets (we counted), there must be $2$ consecutive powerrs of $2$, so for $866$ values of $n$, we actually have accounted for the $2*866$ powers of $2$ (duplets). But for all non-duplet (third, fourth, so on consecutive powers of 2), we didn't count them. And each of them would account for $1$ pair extra.